# Why does Visual Studio leave an empty ItemGroup node in the project file?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, csproj

- Open Visual Studio and create a new C# project of any type.
- Add a new folder to the project and save the project.
- Examine the project file (.csproj) and note that it created a node like this:

  ```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="NewFolder1\" />
  </ItemGroup>
  ```
- Now remove the folder in Visual Studio and save the project.
- Note that in the project file, there is an empty node, like this:

  ```
  <ItemGroup/>
  ```

Removing the empty node doesn't seem to make any difference, so why does VS leave this behind?

Why do I care?  Because commits like this are confusing:

[image]

Comment: I am quite curious myself - but when I see this in my .csproj files, I just trim the rubbish out. Obviously it's not the best solution though...

Comment: Me too, just wondering why it happens

Comment: I think that's just a Visual Studio bug. Still active in the latest at the moment VS2015 Update 2, BTW.

Comment: You might either treat it as bug, or by design. VS attempted to generate only correct XML files, not perfect ones, so it might generate such empty items. The same applies to WinForms/WPF generated C#/XAML files and other scenarios, so messing up your commits is common and we often have no way but to accept that.

Comment: It looks like a bug or just an unexpected behavior. I do not think such a question can be answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, an empty `ItemGroup` is benign, just as an empty `PropertyGroup` is. At worst it's noise in your project file.

Historically, the project file was not really intended for human consumption and only ad-hoc effort was put into keeping it tidy during transformations made by VS.

With the new SDK-style project files, the intent is 100% to have them be human readable and editable. If you see empty groups in VS when using the new project style, it's definitely something the team wants to know about. In such a case, please [report a problem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) and explain in the body that it's for the project system team.

Comment: Thanks.  I wrote this awhile ago, with regard to VS2013.  But good to know that we shouldn't see them anymore with SDK-style projects. :)